# Typed client using HttpClient subclass

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In my app I will have few TypedClient services.
However, these classes will share a bunch of methods.
My solution to this is to create CustomHttpClient:

```
public class CustomHttpClient:HttpClient
{
  //here shared methods
}
```

Then my typed client classes will use this derived class instead of standard HttpClient:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  public SomeService(CustomHttpClient client, IConfiguration configuration){}
}
```

However, if i try to register this service in startup i get an error that there is no suitable constructor for 'MyService' :

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

In the documentation I have found:

[A Typed Client is a class that accepts an HttpClient object (injected through its constructor) and uses it to call some remote HTTP service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Does it mean, that it cannot accept a subclass of HttpClient?
If this is the case, then my only solution would be to implement shared methods as HttpClient extension methods ( i don't really like this solution).
Is there maybe a workaround this, or extension methods are my only way out?
I have tried registering also CustomHttpClient so DI container would find it but the error is still the same.
What can you advise me?

Comment: It seems like Microsoft has preferred Composition over Inheritance, however as the code is open source you might want to customize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it mean, that it cannot accept a subclass of HttpClient?

Yes.

> If this is the case, then my only solution would be to implement shared methods as HttpClient extension methods

No.  Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) typed clients encapsulate an HttpClient, rather than extending it.  You configure the HttpClient in the constructor then add custom methods to the Typed Client that use the encapsulated HttpClient instance.

If you don't want to use the framework's pattern for HttpClient handling, you're free to create your own, but it's probably not worth the effort.

You can have typed clients that share a base class.  eg

```
public class MyBaseTypedClient
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public MyBaseTypedClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
        // GitHub API versioning
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
        // GitHub requires a user-agent
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

        Client = client;
    }

    //other methods

}
public class MyTypedClient : MyBaseTypedClient
{
    public MyTypedClient(HttpClient client) : base(client) { }
}
```

Comment: That's my problem exactly. I have a few Typed Clients, so I will have to repeat those methods in each one. So my choices are   to put the share methods in every typed client class or use extension methods? That's what you are saying?

Comment: You can have all your typed clients inherit a base type, but they all must have constructors that accept an HttpClient.  See updated answer.

Comment: Typed clients should not *be* a client (is-a) but rather *own* (has-a) a client. They can all have a common base, but the relationship to the HttpClient should be ownership and not inheritence. The HttpClientFactory, for example, wouldn't know anything about your subclass of HttpClient so youd have to rewrite that logic completely if you needed it (and you do implicitly since you're trying to use the http client injection) Whereas with the ownership pattern all it has to do is hand out normal clients injected into other containers.

Comment: if we do it like that, then injecting typed clients like services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(); and services.AddHttpClient<IMySecondService, MySecondService>();
 (where MyService and  MySecondService both inherit from MyBaseTypedClient) createas one instance of httpClient that is shared between MyService and MySecondService? or each with their seperate instances?

Comment: Seperate instances, but a shared connection pool.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#httpclient-lifetimes

Comment: I want to alter headers at runtime and cannot alter them at service setup time.

Comment: What's stopping you?  You can still use HttpClient.SendAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add common methods only you can create an Interface with default implementation of those methods, then you would just need to inherit your IMyService with that interface.

You can also have a look at the below link which has some interesting workarounds.

https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1988

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

(1) Create your base MyBaseTypedClient as follows:

```cs
public interface IMyBaseTypedClient
{ 
    //other methods
    //like FetchAsync(), PostAsync()
}

public class MyBaseTypedClient
{
    private HttpClient _client

    public MyBaseTypedClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    //other methods
    //like FetchAsync(), PostAsync()
}
```

(2) Then create your typed clients as follows:

```cs
public interface IServiceOne: IMyBaseTypedClient{ }

public class ServiceOne: MyBaseTypedClient, IServiceOne
{
    public ServiceOne(HttpClient httpClient) : base(httpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IServiceTwo: IMyBaseTypedClient{ }

public class ServiceTwo: MyBaseTypedClient, IServiceTwo
{
    public ServiceTwo(HttpClient httpClient) : base(httpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

(3) Then register as follows

```cs
services
    .AddHttpClient<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://serviceone.com"));
    .AddHttpClient<IServiceTwo, ServiceTwo>(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://servicetwo.com");
```

(4) Then inject as follows

```cs
public void SomeMethodThatNeedsOne(IServiceOne serviceOne)
{
    //etc
}

public void SomeMethodThatNeedsTwo(IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
{
    //etc
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar in my c# library however struggling with designing the extension method. With custom typed clients the design isn't too consumer friendly.

Comment: for the consumer you just ask for IServiceOne or IServiceTwo...which extension method?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have posted the details on this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841856/configuration-of-multiple-http-clients-in-di-and-using-with-different-services-i